# Drupal - displaying the title of the node within a block

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-nodes

I'm needing to dynamically display the title of a node within a block. I would have thought this would be simple, but all the code snippets I've tried don't seem to work (e.g. `<?php print $node->title; ?>`  )

I've checked and tested that the PHP input format is on and working with other PHP bits and bobs, and everything seems OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you wanting to render the page title in a block, thus having the page title display once?  Or to have the normal page title display, as well as having the page title outputted a second time on the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thik this link might be of help:

http://www.g-loaded.eu/2009/05/07/drupal-tip-list-a-nodes-taxonomy-terms-inside-a-block/

Based on it:

```
if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    echo $node->title
}
```

Comment: drupal.api already has function for it: $node = menu_get_object(); print $node->title;

Answer (score 7):

Use [drupal_get_title()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_title/6) for getting the title of the current page.

Comment: drupal_get_title() doesn't work when _cache block_ is enabled under performance settings. Any other solution?

Comment: `drupal_get_title()` is working with *cache block* when the appropriate cache setting for the block is set to *Do not cache*

Answer (score 2):

There is also the option to use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module for this.